# In production mode, the style tag that generated by styled-component has no content

Tags: css, styled-components

#### Reproduction

https://codepen.io/wqh/pen/KKqjaWL

### Steps to reproduce

First, Sorry for my bad English, I hope you can understand what I mean.

Open the codepen link and you can see the phenomenon in the developer tools :

[image]

the generated style tag has no content, but actually effective.

The example is of a low version, but the `5.3.3` version of my project has the same problem

### Expected Behavior

The content of the generated style tag can also be obtained in production mode.

I saw a Q&A that said that the `insertRule`  will cause the content of the style tag to be unavailable.But I use the  [css-vars-ponyfill](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill) to fix vars in IE11, this needs to get the content of the style tag .

### Actual Behavior

In production mode, the generated style tag has no content, this is inconsistent with the development model

Comment: I found a solution, set `SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY=true` before import SC, see that:  https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/constants.ts

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77272654/1112483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles get injected in the DOM differently in development and in production environments.

As mentioned [here (How styles land in the DOM)](https://nocode-nobug.com/things-to-know-about-styled-components/#how-styles-land-in-the-dom),

> This step differs from development mode to production mode.
>
> In development mode, styled-components will inject a style tag inside the head of the page's DOM. This tag will include some data meta properties like the library's version used. And inside the tag, styled-components will append all the styles from your StyledComponents bound to their classNames.
>
> In production mode however, things are a bit different. Since we need to optimize and compress stuff the most we can, the style tag injected by styled-components will still be there, but will be injected as empty.

Edit:

styled-components is handling it differently for 5.0.0 onwards.
As mentioned [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-the-stylesheetmanager-component-in-styled-components-5-0/):

> Modifying the way CSS is injected
> The property disableCSSOMInjections allows us to switch from the CSS
> Object Model (CSSOM) API to a text node-based CSS injection system.
>
> When a browser parses the HTML code of a page, in addition to creating
> a tree of nodes called the DOM (Document Object Model), it creates a
> CSS object model in the form of a tree where each node contains CSS
> style information for a particular DOM element.
>
> This way, to insert or modify the style of a particular node, we can
> use either the DOM API:
>
> ```
>  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = 'blue' Or the
>  CSSOM API:
>
>
>  // Assuming there's a stylesheet in the HTML page const style =
> document.styleSheets[0]; style.sheet.insertRule('#myDiv{background-color: blue}');
> ```
>
> This way, when the property
> disableCSSOMInjections is present or you assign it the value `true`:
>
> ```
> ReactDOM.render(
>    <StyleSheetManager disableCSSOMInjections={true}>
>       <App />
>    </StyleSheetManager>,
>    root
> );
> ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I still cannot find the infected style tags in `production`.

Comment: I have just edited the answer. All components where styled-components is used are susceptible to this issue.

Comment: I don't think this explains why the style tag is empty in production mode tho.